# How to import vector graph into coordinates system?

Tags: graphics, geometry

Suppose I have [smile.pdf](https://www.sendspace.com/file/2lac4u); it's a vector graph.
I can `Import["smile.pdf"]` like below:
[image]

How to put this vector graph into coordinates system? Then I can easy rotate and move it.
[image: this photo just for explanation]

Comment: Can you upload `smile.pdf` somewhere?

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/untitled-2_2   ,just for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the *.pdf file:

```
smiley = First[Import["xx.pdf"]];
```

Inspecting the result, we find the following:

```
Shallow[InputForm[smiley], 7]
   InputForm[Graphics[{Thickness[0.001634], Style[{FilledCurve[<<2>>]},
                       FaceForm[RGBColor[<<4>>]]]}, ImageSize -> {612., 792.},
                      PlotRange -> {{0., 612.}, {0., 792.}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

Particularly important here is the `PlotRange` setting, which lets us reckon where the `FilledCurve[]` representing the shape is centered. One can then do something like this:

```
Graphics[{Blue, First[Cases[smiley, _FilledCurve, ∞]] /. {x_, y_} :> 
         Composition[RotationTransform[60 °],
                     ScalingTransform[{1, 1}/50]][{x, y} - {306, 396}]},
         Background -> Yellow, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: feeling blue]

Comment: Even I change another pdf,I got same result like`InputForm[Graphics[{Thickness[0.001634], Style[{FilledCurve[<<2>>]}`,I cannot understand why

Comment: That's why I asked for a *specific* PDF file; the strategy will need to be modified for a different PDF, since it is unreasonable to expect PDFs to have uniformity.

Comment: Actually, I design vector graph in Adobe Illustrator, and import to Mathematica. Which format is best for import?I mean we should have a general method.

Comment: "I mean we should have a general method." - unless you can enforce in Illustrator that your vector images be within a preset coordinate range, I don't see a general method being possible.

Comment: "I mean we should have a general method." - unless you can enforce in Illustrator that your vector images be within a preset coordinate range, I don't see a general method being possible.

Comment: I don't understand why your method doesn't work even I just change another pdf, http://www.filedropper.com/test4_4

Answer (score 0):

For your example file, after importing the file, just grab the first element which you need and reconstruct graphics with the geometric transformation you want.

If you check `InputForm[test4]` like J.M. suggested, you can see why you only need to take the first element.

```
test4 = First[Import["test4.pdf"]];
Shallow[InputForm[test4], 7]
```

> ```
> InputForm[ Graphics[{ Thickness[0.0016339869281045752`],  Style[{
> FilledCurve[ Skeleton[2]]},  FaceForm[ RGBColor[ Skeleton[4]]]], 
> Style[{ JoinedCurve[ Skeleton[3]]},  JoinForm[{ Skeleton[2]}]], 
> Style[{ FilledCurve[ Skeleton[2]]}, 
> Thickness[0.0016339869281045752`]]}, ImageSize -> {612., 792.},   
> PlotRange -> {{0., 612.}, {0., 792.}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
> ```

```
Graphics[Translate[Rotate[test4[[1]], 30 Degree], {-290, -411}], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: where did you get `-290,-411`?

Comment: I just manually typed it.